# Hide Bootstrap 4 Columns with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 4 columns, but when I hide one or more it changes the columns width completely like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 hide-this">col-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 hide-this">col-2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">col-2</div>
</div>
```

If I hide all the cols with the `hide-this` class it changes the width of the only one that´s still visible

```
$('.hide-this').hide();
```

How can I maintain the width of the column that´s still visible?

Comment: Try to add class `.d-sm-none` or others.

Comment: Each col will still maintain the same width, but when you hide the first 2, the right col slides to the left. is this what you mean? Do you want the col to maintain the same position in the row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offset-md-6`:

```
$('.hide-this').hide();
$('.col-md-3').addClass('offset-md-6');
```

Check [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xjm9km9r/4/), I add another class to the specific column so there is no need to use `col-md-3` as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

> it changes the columns width

It doesn't change the column width. What is actually happening is that when a column is removed, other columns ***move*** to fill the newly created gap. But the width of the columns remains the same.

So, the question now becomes: What can you do to prevent them from moving to fill the newly created gap?

You can use responsive Bootstrap 4 `offset` classes in this case. And also use the `d-none` class (display:none) for hiding elements.

So, if, for example, you want to hide the first column, you add the `d-none` class to that and then add the `offset-md-3` class to the following column to prevent it from moving into the gap like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary d-none">col-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-secondary offset-md-3">col-2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-warning">col-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-success">col-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery, in that case, would be something like.

```
$('.bg-primary').addClass('d-none');
$('div.bg-primary').next().addClass('offset-md-3');
```

The `md` in `offset-md-3` means that the offset will only happen on screens that are `md` or larger and won't happen on screens that are smaller than `md` (medium). That's what you want because in this case, they'll all stack up on smaller screens.

If you then want to hide the second column, you add the `d-none` class to it but this time you'll need to add `offset-md-6` to the following column because now you have removed 2 columns with the width of 3 units each.

So, your HTML would now change to this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary d-none">col-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-secondary d-none">col-2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-warning offset-md-6">col-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-success">col-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you only wanted to hide a column on screens that are `md` or larger but show it on smaller screens, then you'd use `d-md-none` instead of `d-none`.

Comment: I have a grid of 400 products. I can´t deal with offsets. Basically I want to show columns with specific classes and keep them in the width I specified

Comment: You might need to re-read my answer a couple of times because you might have missed the fact that the width doesn't change. And yet you are still talking about the "width". Also, in the case of a grid with "400 products," it appears that you something completely different than what you explained in the question. But what it is that you actually want, still remains a bit a "mystery" at this point.